# C++ QT Library Modules

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to include as minimum QT Libraries as possible.. Therefore I need to know the exact hierarchy of QT Libraries, like which is included in which?

e.g. I've  `#include <QInputDialog>` and `#include <QLabel>` and they are both can be replaced with `#include <QWidget>`

Comment: why? You should include what you use. Reyling on transitive includes will result in an uncontrollable mess pretty fast

Comment: Note that you're referring to header files rather than libraries.  As per the comment above, however, the general advice is to 'include what you use' .

Comment: Exactly, The thing is I'm using PCH (Precompiled Headers)... That's why I'm trying to include the main libraries to compile it once !

Comment: It should not matter in your precomplied header generation. Just include the Qt headers that your code needs.